# How are the content in files are listed?

Tags: java, file

I could not find any information on the internet about this. For instance, if I have integers in my file. are those integer listed as like an array with index or random like Linkedlist?

In my project I need to read integers from the file , 4 at a time and store it in another file so how can reference to each integer in the file?

Comment: A file is a sequence of bytes, non? So, they are, sequential?

Comment: pls share your study/struggle done so far. Share details like code, format of input etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A file is nothing but a sequence of bytes. There is no structure to it whatsoever unless you fetch the content in the memory. Interpreting a file depends upon the kind of the file you are trying to read. So, for example, in your case, if numbers are separated by end-of-line characters, you can read the file line by line (which means reading a chunk until you discover an `endl` or `'\n'`).

Answer (score 0):

As Kevin said, File in Java is a sequence of Bytes. You can read the file either using Byte steam or Character stream. So if the Inout file has integers which are in different lines, then you can read one line at a time and store it temporarily so that once you read 4 lines (4 integers), you can do the processing task.